# Debugging hackerrank week of code Lazy Sorting

Tags: algorithm, probability

I am doing a question on hackerrank(https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w21/challenges/lazy-sorting) right now, and I am confused as to why doesn't my code fulfill the requirements. The questions asks:

Logan is cleaning his apartment. In particular, he must sort his old favorite sequence, P, of N positive integers in nondecreasing order. He's tired from a long day, so he invented an easy way (in his opinion) to do this job. His algorithm can be described by the following pseudocode:

```
while isNotSorted(P) do {   
    WaitOneMinute();
    RandomShuffle(P)
}
```

Can you determine the expected number of minutes that Logan will spend waiting for to be sorted?

**Input format:**

The first line contains a single integer, N, denoting the size of permutation .The second line contains N space-separated integers describing the respective elements in the sequence's current order, P_0, P_1 ... P_N-1.

**Constraints:**
2 <= N <= 18
1 <= P_i <= 100

**Output format:**

Print the expected number of minutes Logan must wait for P to be sorted, rounded to a scale of exactly 6 decimal places (i.e.,1.234567 format).

**Sample input:**

2 
5 2

**Sample output:**
2.000000

**Explanation**

There are two permutations possible after a random shuffle, and each of them has probability 0.5. The probability to get the sequence sorted after the first minute is 0.5. The probability that will be sorted after the second minute is 0.25, the probability will be sorted after the third minute is 0.125, and so on. The expected number of minutes hence equals to:

summation of i*2^-i where i goes from 1 to infinity = 2

I wrote my code in c++ as follow:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main() {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 

    map <int, int> m; //create a map to store the number of repetitions of each number
    int N;  //number of elements in list
    //calculate the number of permutations
    cin >> N;
    int j;
    int total_perm = 1;
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cin >> temp;
        //if temp exists, add one to the value of m[temp], else initialize a new key value pair
        if (m.find(temp) == m.end()){
            m[temp] = 1;
        }else{
            m[temp] += 1;
        }
        total_perm *= i+1;
    }
    //calculate permutations taking into account of repetitions
    for (map<int,int>::iterator iter = m.begin(); iter != m.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if (iter -> second > 1){
            temp  = iter -> second;
            while (temp > 1){
                total_perm = total_perm / temp;
                temp -= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    float recur = 1 / float(total_perm);
    float prev;
    float current = recur;
    float error = 1;
    int count = 1;
    //print expected number of minutes up to 6 sig fig
    if (total_perm == 1){
        printf("%6f", recur);
    }else{
        while (error > 0.0000001){
            count += 1;
            prev = current;
            current = prev + float(count)*float(1-recur)*pow(recur,count-1);
            error = abs(current - prev);
        }
        printf("%6f", prev);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't really care about the competition, it's more about learning for me, so I would really appreciate it if someone can point out where I was wrong.

Comment: Hi Brenda, wlcm to stackoverflow. Questions on stack-overflow should be self-contained -- if there's requirements that your code should meet, they should be included in the question and not just a link (although the link is welcome too, assuming it's not broken like this one is). If you can't figure out why the code doesn't meet the (explicit) requirements, you should say what you've done to find the problem, otherwise it's a guess just where you're stuck. Just including code and saying that some external website said your code wasn't right will tend to get your question downvoted and closed.

Comment: HI Paul, thanks for the tip! I'll change it asap!

Comment: Hi Brenda, you've copied the problem into your question, but you've still not said why your code's not working. For example, including an input for which your code produces the wrong value (and the expected value) would be typical when producing a "minimal complete and verifiable example". See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am not familiar with C++ so I don't know exactly what your code is doing. I did, however, solve this problem. It's pretty cheeky and I think they posed the problem the way they did just to be confusing. So the important piece of knowledge here is that for an event with probability p, the expected number of trials until a success is 1/p. Since each trial here costs us a minute, that means we can find the expected number of trials and add ".000000" to the end.

So how do you do that? Well each permutation of the numbers is equally likely to occur, which means that if we can find how many permutations there are, we can find p. And then we take 1/p to get E[time]. But notice that each permutation has probability 1/p of occurring, where p is the total number of permutations. So really E[time] = number of permutations. I leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is just simple problem.
This problem looks like bogo sort.
How many unique permutations of the given array are possible? In the sample case, there are two permutations possible, so the expected time for any one permutation to occur is 2.000000. Extend this approach to the generic case, taking into account any repeated numbers.

However in the question, the numbers can be repeated. This reduces the number of unique permutations, and thus the answer.

Just find the number of unique permutations of the array, upto 6 decimal places. That is your answer.

Think about if array is sorted then what happen?

E.g
if test case is

5 5

5 4 3 2 1

then ans would be 120.000000 (5!/1!)

5 5

1 2 3 4 5

then ans would be 0.000000 in your question.

5 5

2 2 2 2 2

then also ans would be 0.000000

5 5

5 1 2 2 3

then ans is 60.000000

In general ans is  if array is not sorted : N!/P!*Q!.. and so on..

Here is another useful link:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844133/expectation-over-sequencial-random-shuffles